# Oracle Data Pump - export from Enterprise Edition to Standard Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am migrating from an Enterprise Edition of Oracle 10g to a Standard Edition of Oracle 10g and I was wondering if anyone has experience doing this.  I've searched around and I can't really find a definitive answer, but it seems like the features in Enterprise Edition will not smoothly translate to an import into a Standard Edition Oracle instance.

Does anyone have experience doing this?  So far I have just tried expdp on Enterprise Edition and impdp into Standard Edition, but the features that exist in Enterprise Edition (like partitioning, etc.) cause errors when importing to Standard Edition.

Comment: Can you import it into another schema on the EE Oracle, convert partitioned tables to non-partitioned and re-export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [DBMS_METADATA with a TRANSFORM to disable the storage clauses](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_metada.htm#1019576)

This should allow you to get all the table structures in a format that you can create the table in SE. Then you can just import the rows on top of the tables you've created.

You won't be able to do anything about bitmap indexes though.

Comment: Ok, cool.  So it looks like I need to export the table structures, remove any of the unsupported features like bitmap indexes, partitions, etc. and create those tables within SE.  Then export the data from EE and import just the data into SE, since I've already created the tables.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the old ways work.  Instead of the data pump you can try using the older exp and imp. Get rid of table partitioning and bit map indexes.